# Como medir complexidade temporal de algoritmos de ordenação?

Tags: java, classificação, complexidade-de-algoritmo

Dado um algoritmo de ordenação, por exemplo burble sort, como medir seu tempo de execução?

Por exemplo digamos que a entrada da vetor ou lista tem um tamanho de 1000 elementos, qual o tempo medido em "ms" que devo "esperar", dado que tempo médio desse algoritmo é O(n^2)?

[image: Resumo]

Como calcular o tempo x dado a formula de cálculo O(n^2) e y tempo medido através da execução do algoritmo, dado a figura acima?

Comment: Pedro, acho que as coisas não são tão diretas assim. Complexidade assintotica assume que todas as operações são iguais (o que não é verdade), desconsidera o pipeline, predições de branches, etc. Não é muito difícil encontrar algoritmos quadráticos mais rápidos que contrapartes `n log(n)` para todo um range de possibilidades. Na prática acho que tentar estimar o tempo de execução real de um algoritmo pela complexidade assintotica * tempo médio por operação não vai dar muito certo.

Comment: A única forma é criando um código e um *roll* de dados e testando. Mesmo este teste só será válido nas condições específicas onde está sendo testando. Mas se a intenção é saber outra coisa, modifique a pergunta para expressar isto melhor.

Comment: eu queria saber nesse caso que citei... o tempo esperado seria de O(1000000) oq em ms isso representa? e dado esse tempo como encontrar um tempo execução aproximado desse algoritmo em java?

Comment: E a resposta é: não dá. Você pode tentar encontrar uma (má) estimativa para o seu programa, na sua linguagem, no seu computador, no seu sistema operacional, na sua VM, sobre o load atual do seu sistema, com as políticas atuais de GC na JVM, etc, etc. Porém não existe uma tradução direta de `n` para `ms`. Você terá que mensurar (rodando o algoritmo milhares de vezes para diversos tamanhos de entrada, tentando buscar um valor médio por operação).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você está tentando fazer uma correlação entre a teoria e a prática e como sabemos na teoria ambas são iguais, na prática não.

**Teoria**: Usando notação O() você estuda o comportamento do algoritmo, i.e. Como seria o custo* em função do tamanho da entrada. Note que a notação O() não vai nos dar uma função com parâmetros bem definidos (não tem como adivinhar os "K"), apenas vai nos dizer se é polinomial, exponencial, etc.
Note que o custo* não é em tempo mas em "operações" e mesmo essas operações dependem de uma definição no seu problema. Em geral para algoritmos de ordenação as operações são consideradas os swaps de itens.

Lembre-se que nesses algoritmos é comum haver melhor caso é pior caso (ex lista está ordenada, lista está ordenada em ordem decrescente) e mesmo isso pode afetar seus testes.

**Prática**: Para verificar quanto tempo um programa leva para rodar vai depender de vários fatores de hardware: CPU, Memória, etc.
fatores de sistema: Qual sistema operacional, etc.
fatores de tecnologia: Qual linguagem/compilador usado, etc
fatores etc: carga de outros sistemas sendo usados como anti-vírus, firewall, etc.

Para verificar isso você vai colocar seu programa para rodar e medir quanto tempo ele levou para terminar de processar uma massa de dados específica. Se você plotar um gráfico com esses resultados para massas de dados de tamanhos diferentes em tese o gráfico vai +- aderir ao gráfico esperado na teoria (e você pode até arriscar encontrar as contantes, os "K"s). Claro que vários fatores vão contribuir para que isso nãos seja tão simples, como usar muita memória e o SO começar a usar paginação.
Além disso seu programa irá fazer várias operações, mesmo operações de chamada do SO e outros detalhes que não estão previstos no modelo.

**Resumo**: Não há correlação direta entre o custo teórico de um algoritmo calculado com big O e o tempo em ms de cada operação. Você pode até tentar encontrar uma correlação para um cenário em particular mas apenas em "condições de laboratório" e para um ambiente muito específico.